# sed or awk combining two files with sum

Tags: awk, sed, squid

We have script that strips everything except domain names from squid access.log and reports total hits for each URL, I have a generated two files one with cache hits and other with cache miss, I am looking for a way to combine these files as below -

`cat TCP_MISS_data.txt`

```
Domains    CacheMiss
abc.com    21
def.com    38
xyz.com    12
```

`cat TCP_HITS_data.txt`

```
Domains  CacheHits
def.com  28
abc.com  10
xyz.com
```

`cat Combined_data.txt`

```
Domains    CacheMiss CacheHits  TotalHits
abc.com     21        10          31
def.com     38        28          66
xyz.com     12        0           12
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update:

I used the below awk one liner to strip domains and hits from access log, and it outputs one file with all domains and their hits regardless of HITS and MISSES.

```
cat access.log | awk '{print $7}' | awk '!/^http/{sub(/^/,"http://")}1' | awk -F"/" '{print $3}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}' | awk -F"." '{f1=NF;f2=NF-1;print $f2 "." $f1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

To seperate the hits and misses I did below -

```
cat access.log | grep TCP_MISS | awk '{print $7}' | awk '!/^http/{sub(/^/,"http://")}1' | awk -F"/" '{print $3}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}' | awk -F"." '{f1=NF;f2=NF-1;print $f2 "." $f1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n > TCP_MISS_data

cat access.log | grep TCP_HIT | awk '{print $7}' | awk '!/^http/{sub(/^/,"http://")}1' | awk -F"/" '{print $3}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}' | awk -F"." '{f1=NF;f2=NF-1;print $f2 "." $f1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n > TCP_HITS_data
```

Now I ended up with two files, TCP_MISS_data and TCP_HITS_data they have un-equal rows and Im trying to combine these two file as explained in my above post.

Comment: Where are you stuck here?

Comment: Tom I am still a novice at awk, but i'l trying and complete the Kent's one liner. Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with being a novice, you just need to show some research effort in your question. If you have tried something yourself but it's not working, [edit] your question to show us that. Otherwise it is not clear exactly where your problem lies and it seems like you just want someone to write some code for you.

Answer (score 3):

This oneliner may do the job:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
     $1 in a{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $1,a[$1],($2?$2:0),(FNR>1?a[$1]+$2:"TotalHits")}' missFile hitFile
```

To get the "pretty" output format, you can either adjust the `printf` format or simply pipe the result to `column -t` like `awk ..... |column -t`

with your example input:

```
kent$  head f*
==> f1 <==
Domains    CacheMiss
abc.com    21
def.com    38
xyz.com    12

==> f2 <==
Domains  CacheHits
def.com  28
abc.com  10
xyz.com

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $1,a[$1],($2?$2:0),(FNR>1?a[$1]+$2:"TotalHits")}' f1 f2|column -t
Domains  CacheMiss  CacheHits  TotalHits
def.com  38         28         66
abc.com  21         10         31
xyz.com  12         0          12
```

#### Edit:

add some explanation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}           #process the first file, store in a hashtable, key:col1, value:col2
$1 in a                               #starting processing 2nd file, if file2.col1 in hashtable, do followings:
{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $1,a[$1],    #printf output with format
($2?$2:0),                            #if file2.cols was empty, we take it as 0
(FNR>1?a[$1]+$2:"TotalHits")          #if first line, we dont do sum, print "totalHits" text
}' f1 f2                              #two input files
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain your script, in the hope that next time the OP encounters any kind of issue, their first idea is to get someone else to solve it for them here.

Comment: @TomFenech ok, I added some description, even though I think the codes are straightforward enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kent, the the script you provided is working only for 5 lines ie If f2 has 5 lines and f1 has 100 lines then its matching values only for 5 domains in f1. I needed to get hits and misses for all 100 lines in f1, can It can display 0 in TotalHits if domain is not present f1? Thanks again.

Comment: You should bring those requirement in your question. Try DIY a little bit, I have finished the part of : "if some key in hashtable", you can try the `else` part.